# Livewire send form to controller by using route

Tags: php, laravel

I am building a web app and also Restful API where I need to use the same controller because they do the same thing. However, Livewire seems cannot send the data to the POST route.

So, what I am gonna try to achieve is to send a traditional form data with csrf token to the route. Here is my livewire sample file

```
    $controllerAgencyInquiry = new AgencyInquiryController();
    switch ($this->inquiry_type) {
        case 'buying':
            $request = new AgencyInquiryBuyingRequest($input);
            $res = $controllerAgencyInquiry->storeBuying(request: $request, agency: $agency);
            break;

        case 'selling':
            $request = new AgencyInquirySellingRequest($input);
            $res = $controllerAgencyInquiry->storeSelling(request: $request, agency: $agency);
            break;
    }
```

The code above shows the data will certainly bypass the middleware from route which I have set in web.php (route).

Here is the form

```
<!-- Showing form -->
<form wire:submit="assign">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <x-input-label for="agency_agent_id" :value="__('Choose :name',['name' => __('Agent')])" :required="true" />
        <x-select-input-post wire:model="agency_agent_id" :result="$agents" :show="__('Choose :name',['name' => __('Agent')])"/>
        <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('agency_agent_id')" class="mt-2" />
    </div>
    <div class="flex justify-end">
        <x-primary-button>{{ __('Assign') }} <i class="ps-2 fa-solid fa-circle-right"></i></x-primary-button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the route file

```
    Route::post('/manage/agency/inquiry/store-buying',[AgencyInquiryController::class,['storeBuying']]);
    Route::post('/manage/agency/inquiry/store-selling',[AgencyInquiryController::class,['storeSelling']]);
```

Route::post('/manage/agency/inquiry/assign',[AgencyInquiryController::class,['assign']]);

So, how do I send the data to route post?

I checked the documentation
https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/forms

You could see that the form is sending data automatically without going to route.

I am doing this because the controller is plugged with some traits where I just want to send any data either from web or app in the same controller.

Comment: "what I am gonna try to achieve is to send a traditional form data with csrf token" where is your traditional form?